# Vim installed with Git for windows does not work correctly in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, vim, git

I am on Windows 10. I first installed [Git for windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) and
then I installed `posh-git` in PowerShell.

Git installed fine into the folder `C:\Program Files\Git` which included `vim.exe` in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\`.

I can run `vim.exe` from PowerShell like this:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vim.exe' foo.txt
```

which works fine. But when I do `git commit` in PowerShell, `git` brings up `vim.exe` with the following text:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#       new file:   a.txt
#
```

If I press <kbd>i</kbd> I enter insert mode. The problem is that now the space key does not move the text to the right. It simply moves the cursor to the left and it is impossible to delete the text that is already there:

[image]

As can be seen from the above screen shot, the predeclared text cannot be erased. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your terminal settings are not correct.  Programs designed for Unix systems require the `TERM` environment variable to be set in order to function correctly.  This tells the program's terminal library how to interpret characters that are typed and how to render data properly on the screen.

Values of `TERM` that folks have seen work with PowerShell in the past, according to some Googling, include `cygwin` and `msys`.  If you're using the new Microsoft Terminal, you may also be able to use `xterm-256color`.

If you're not sure how to set an environment variable, here's [an article that explains it](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2019/03/28/environment-variables-in-powershell.aspx).

Comment: Running `$env:TERM` gives no output. But if it is the `TERM` variable, why does running `vim.exe` directly (not indirectly through `git commit`) work fine?

Comment: I tried running `$env:TERM = 'msys'` before running `git commit` and it actually works!